# Query in 2 tables - JOIN

Tags: mysql, join

I am struggling in MySQL. I have 2 Tables, one Table with all the data and 1 table with generic information about a node.

**dataTable**

- ID
- Name

**nodeTable**

- ID
- Address

Now I have the Address and I want to build a query in which the *Name* is returned. I probably should use a JOIN but the last time I worked with MySQL goes way back.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Answer (score 2):

```
select
    dataTable.name
from
    dataTable
    inner join nodeTable on
        dataTable.ID = nodeTable.ID   
where
    nodeTable.adress = 'your address'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I need to play more often with mysql :-)

Answer (score 0):

Does the below code fulfill your needs?

```
select Name 
  from dataTable, nodeTable 
 where dataTable.ID = nodeTable.ID
   and Address = 'Rathausstrasse'
```

Comment: Don't encourage a old JOIN style that is over 25 years old use proper INNER JOIN syntax

Comment: its just the style - it doesn't make a difference performance wise - the query optimizer is smart enough nowadays...

Comment: the newer INNER JOIN syntax is easier to read and understand,, performance wise indeed makes no difference

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.name
from dataTable d, nodeTable n
on d.id = n.id
where n.address = '10 Main St.';
```

Comment: Don't encourage a old JOIN style that is over 25 years old use proper INNER JOIN syntax